# Centering my variables decreases the condition indices

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multicollinearity

In my regression model, one of my condition indices is very high, but only the intercept and one of the eplanatory variables have a large variance decomposition proportion for this index.
The VIF is small for this variable.

After centering my variables, the indices became much smaller.

How should I interpret this?